# Create a route animation with a large amount of lines

Tags: pyqgis, route, animation, gui

I am trying to build a user interface which allows, after clicking "play", to see a route appearing on the map canvas, every x seconds, to show someone moving through a route. I have to store these lines and vertices into a layer, as I will need them later to perform spatial calculation.

I came up with this function, which I am trying to call every 2-3 seconds to see the route (I have another function before this that creates a layer from a list of coordinates).

```
def add_points (self, step):       
    self.feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(self.MyListPointsQGS[step:step+2]))
    self.feature.setAttributes([1, self.ListePointsQGS[step].x(), self.ListePointsQGS[step].y(), self.ListePointsQGS[step+2].x(), self.ListePointsQGS[step+2].y()]) 
    self.pr.addFeature(self.feature)
    self.layer.commitChanges()
```

I am getting an out of range error with the `setAttribute` line for the last entry but it's not the problem for now, I end up with a layer with all the lines and the starting/ending coordinates of it. This function, when used in a loop, creates lines between coordinates coming from a pandas Dataframe. I don't know any GeoPandas yet, maybe it is a solution?

This function within my class works really well, I can build a route from 60.000 points in just a few seconds (2 secs to create the layer, 0.5 to add all of the lines to the attribute table), but I can't figure out how to create a sort of animation to see the route getting drawn into the canvas.

I have tried using the `QgsRubberBand` class for days (without creating a vector layer, just from my coordinates) but couldn't figure out how to use it, and anyway this solution seems (?) to be pretty slow as I will have a large dataset (probably hundreds of thousands of lines) and that I need to keep tracks of the points of the route to perform calculation.

I have tried to call `add_points()` every 3 secs with `time.sleep(3)`, but the program freezes instantly, apparently it rarely works on QGIS.

I have tried using the answer from this question:[How to make Python wait while QGIS renders a shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301747/how-to-make-python-wait-while-qgis-renders-a-shapefile).

```
def spin(seconds):
    """Pause for set amount of seconds, replaces time.sleep so program doesn't stall"""

    time_end = time.time() + seconds
    while time.time() < time_end:
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
```

But QGIS always end up throwing an error `"module 'qgis.PyQt.QtGui' has no attribute 'QApplication'"`, I tried a few different ones but I don't know anything about Qt, maybe I should start a tutorial?

I also thought I could load the layer with all the attributes at once, and then make appearing all of the features one by one every x seconds with this solution.

```
#Do any spacial query which returns some features
features = lyrPnts.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(geomPoly.boundingBox()))

#build the query string
strsel="gid IN ("
for feat in features:
    if feat.geometry().intersects(geomPoly):
        strsel=strsel+ "'" + str(feat.id()) + "',"

#Closes the string with a parenthesis
strsel=strsel[:-1] + ")"
#Hides the undesired features
lyrPnts.setSubsetString(strsel)
```

but again I couldn't find how to do it, no error but it doesn't work.

So now I am pretty lost, what do you think could be the solution, as I need to have at the end (I will set a GUI later, for now I just need how to start "play") a GUI that allow a play, stop and backwards button?

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in temporal controller? If so, why can't you use it?

Comment: I saw videos about it without programming but it didn't seemed to fit my needs, I just looked now and indeed it might do the job much more easily than what I thought, I didn't thought that I could use it with python, I'll look it up further thanks !